# store variable within linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I faced this situation today and could not find on the web what I wanted.

Look at this code,

```
myCollection.Select(g => new ReportLine
{
    cds = (sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)) != null ? 
               sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)).USER != null?
                  sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)).USER.USER_FIRSTNAME : "": "")
                                + " " +
          (sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)) != null ?
               sectors.Where(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)).FirstOrDefault().USER != null?
                  sectors.Where(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE)).FirstOrDefault().USER.LASTNAME : "" : "")
});
```

Basically "myCollection" is a list of a deep class and this request goes into it extract a first and last name and put them in an other class while checking if there is no null values.

You noticed to achieve that I checked the same thing 6 times:

```
sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE))
```

(probably painful for performance)

Does a way exists to "store" the value within the linq expression ? something like this:

```
myCollection.Select(g => new ReportLine
{
    cds = ((var tmp =sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE))) != null ? 
               tmp.USER != null?
                  tmp.USER.USER_FIRSTNAME + "" + tmp.USER.LASTNAME: "": "")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myCollection.Select(g => { 
    var sect_code = g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE;
    var sector = sectors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SECT_CODE.Equals(sect_code));
    var firstName = sector != null ? 
        (sector.USER != null ? sector.USER.USER_FIRSTNAME: "") : 
        "";
    var lastName = sector != null ? 
        (sector.USER != null ? sector.USER.LASTNAME : "") : 
        "";
    return new ReportLine
    {
        cds = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName)
    };
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure that EF won't be able to properly translate that.

Comment: @Servy, why not? That is standard linq? Do you mean because it won't be able to lookup `Contract` then `Station` and `Sector`? If you ask me that is not the above linq that is the problem, rather it is EF, if used, and that he has a really nested structure in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably going to have to change to long-hand LINQ to make it happen, but you can use [LINQ's let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to assign variables in the middle of an expression.

Comment: What is long-hand LINQ? I see no problem in using the fluent syntax.

Comment: See the link in the answer for an example.  It's a more verbose, SQL-ish way to write the same expressions.

Comment: I know what the regular linq syntax is, and the let clause, I just thought you meant something else when you wrote long-hand LINQ, since I've never heard it before. But why did you thought he had to change to that syntax?

Answer (score -1):

You could extract the logic in the `Select` statement to a separate method, and call that inside the `Select` statement?

Something like...

```
private string Foo(Sector input)
{
    var tmp = g.SECT_CODE.Equals etc etc
    return tmp.USER != null ? etc etc
}
```

...

```
myCollection.Select(g => Foo(g))
```

Comment: If you make this change then EF won't be able to parse the code to translate it into SQL.

Comment: Was it specified that this was a SQL call?

Comment: The question is tagged as EF.

Comment: You're not necessarily interacting with SQL even if you're using EF.

Comment: But the expressions *do* need to be parseable, and this isn't going to allow for that.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that sentiment. If you're writing something that is interacting with a back-end db then yes maybe. If you've already returned a list locally and are manipulating it, then the solution I proposed here works just fine. One can argue as to the merits of a parseable solution, or doing it inline as others have proposed. I would argue that this solution is clean, easily readable and promotes reusability. Nonetheless, your opinion is your own so fair enough if you think it really needs downvoting.

Comment: Then you should make it clear that your solution requires pulling *the entire database table* down into memory so that you can filter out the one record that is needed in the application, rather than on the database side.  In most applications that's not going to be acceptable.

Comment: You're still assuming that the answer is starting at the db interaction end. Also many many scenarios would involve a filtered set being pulled locally and then further operations and filters being performed on them. I notice you have the same criticism of the answer accepted by the OP. Anyway, I'll leave it here as it seems that furthering this debate won't contribute anything further useful.

Answer (score -1):

> myCollection.Select(g => { 
>   var temp=sectors.FirstOrDefault(); ...
>
> return new ReportLine(){..};
>
> })

Answer (score -1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
myCollection.Select(g => new ReportLine
{
    cds =  (from s in sectors
            where s.SECT_CODE.Equals(g.Contract.Station.Sector.SECT_CODE) && s.USER != null
            select string.Format("{0} {1}", s.USER.USER_FIRSTNAME, s.USER.USER_LASTNAME)).FirstOrDefault() ?? " "
});
```